# Doc xml Parser android local xml file reading

Tags: android

I have one local xml file. I am storing here : res/xml/myxml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
<lists>
    <tag>College Website</tag>
    <value>http://www.nitk.ac.in/</value>
    <lastupdate>04-07-2012</lastupdate>
</lists>
<lists>
    <tag>College Images</tag>
    <value>http://studentsworld.nitk.ac.in/index.php?q=convocation.html</value>
    <lastupdate>25-9-2011</lastupdate>
</lists>
</list>
```

I have doc for loop. but how to connect local xml file in doc parser. i don't want url model, i want to a local xml file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            tag[i] = new TextView(this);
            value[i] = new TextView(this);
            lastupdate[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("tag");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            tag[i].setText("tag = " + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value");
            Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
            websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
            value[i].setText("value = " + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList lastupdateList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("tag");
            Element lastupdateElement = (Element) lastupdateList.item(0);
            lastupdateList = lastupdateElement.getChildNodes();
            lastupdate[i].setText("lastupdate = " + ((Node) lastupdateList.item(0)).getNodeValue());



            layout.addView(tag[i]);
            layout.addView(value[i]);
            layout.addView(lastupdate[i]);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

I have main.xml file
please send me a code

Comment: [See this Example...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser.html) and continue with for loop of nodelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put you XML file in assets folder and try this

`InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("simple.xml");`

and try this

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder= dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(raw);
....
...
```

Answer (score 1):

put you XML file in **assets** folder and Try this way

```
 String xml;
 Document doc;
 try{
 xml=getXML(getAssets().open("yourxmlfilename.xml"));
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.d("Error",e.toString());
  }
 doc = XMLfromString(xml);
```

where **getXML** and  **XMLfromString** method are as shown below

```
 //getXML   method
 public static String getXML(InputStream is)throws IOException {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while(result != -1) {
      byte b = (byte)result;
      buf.write(b);
      result = bis.read();
    }        
    return buf.toString();
}


   //XMLfromString   method
  public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){
     Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

          InputSource is = new InputSource();
              is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
              doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
          System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
          return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
          System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
          return null;
        }

            return doc;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code for parse local xml,

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlfile);
```

And then parse inputstream,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance ();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder ();
Document document = db.parse(in, null);
```